# Any way to send 404 status code at the time of redirection while using self routes in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Any method to send 404 status code at the time of redirection while using self routes in development mode as well as in production mode ?**

Comment: What do you mean by term "self routes"? Please provide some code example that you've tried and failed to make work as you want.

Comment: You probably are trying to define your own error_page. In that case, create a controller action, route and view like `my_error_page` and then simply `redirect_to my_error_page_[my_controller]_path` on some condition that you want?